# setTitleView strange behaviour in iOS 5 - objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I try to set `UILabel` as `titleView` using `[self.navigationItem setTitleView:musicArtist];` method, but it works strange with different iOS versions. UINavigationBar is in `UIPopoverController`.
Here is iOS 4.3 screenshot:

[image]

As you can see it looks good. But when I switch iOS simulator at iOS 5.x I receive another result:
[image]

UILabel AutioSize settings are:

[image]

And finally If I change UILabel AutoSizing to this:

[image]

I receive this result at both iOS versions:

[image]

Where could be the problem and how to get first result at all iOS versions?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved when I've removed all AutoResizing settings.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to use the origin `x` and `y` like `{0, 0}`? In the screenshots you are using `y=131` so when you attach it to `titleView` it will not show.